# swiperjs слайд javascript

Tags: javascript

Имеются два вот таких слайдеров на сайте https://swiperjs.com/, как сделать что бы они были не зависимы друг от друга ? то есть нажимаешь на один и они оба повторяются

Comment: Предоставьте минимальное демо (HTML + js) судя по документации плагина все работает.

Comment: Вы противоречите себе в своем же вопросе. "Не зависимы" и "нажимаешь на один и они оба повторяются" в принципе конфликтующие понятия. Что именно вам нужно? Приведите конкретный пример.